# Google Maps: org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to json object

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, google-maps

I am getting the values of latitude and longitude from mysql database table where both fields data type is double and in php file i am putting these values in an array and sending them as a response to json. My logcat shows these values correct but it also says that

> "org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to json object"

and i cannot see the result on the map i want from lat and long but there is some other place on the map. Here is my java code part which gets values from php. So how can i handle this conversion to get these values as is as they are coming from php, so that i can see the stored location in database.

```
JSONObject json_user1 = new JSONObject(responseFromPHP);

        JSONObject json_user2 = json_user1.getJSONObject("latlong");

        double latitude=Double.parseDouble((json_user2.getString(TAG_LATITUDE)));

        double longitude=Double.parseDouble((json_user2.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE)));
                    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
            Marker Lahore = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("Lahore"));
         // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 5));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

LogCAT:
[image]

```
10-10 22:49:47.655: D/Show lat n long:(30670): {"success":1,"latlongs":[{"longitude":"74.3436","latitude":"31.5497"}]}
10-10 22:49:47.655: W/System.err(30670): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"longitude":"74.3436","latitude":"31.5497"}] at latlongs of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-10 22:49:47.660: W/System.err(30670):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
10-10 22:49:47.660: W/System.err(30670):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
10-10 22:49:47.660: W/System.err(30670):    at com.DRMS.disas_recovery.MainActivity$LoadMap.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:80)
10-10 22:49:47.660: W/System.err(30670):    at com.DRMS.disas_recovery.MainActivity$LoadMap.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
10-10 22:49:47.665: W/System.err(30670):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php


$response = array();


require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM tbl_map WHERE map_id=1") or die(mysql_error());



if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["latlongs"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $latlong = array();
        $latlong["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
        $latlong["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];
        array_push($response["latlongs"], $latlong);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error nothing found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
JSONObject json_user2 = json_user1.getJSONObject("latlong");
```

`json_user1.get("latlong")` is a `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`. You can tell because the string starts with a `[` not a `{`, which correspond to `Array` and `Object` respectively.

Try the following.

```
JSONArray json_user2 = json_user1.getJSONArray("latlong");
```

That should work fine for you.

Comment: now i get another error on this line `double latitude=Double.parseDouble((json_user2.getString(TAG_LATITUDE)));`. And Error is **The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Comment: Well sure, you have an array of `JSONObjects` in your `JSONArray`, not simple properties (strings).. I would read the documentation of JSONArray - http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html, before trying to work with it.